# finviz-api not exporting the first row in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, api, jupyter-lab

I followed the instructions of the finviz-api as illustrated here:

https://github.com/mariostoev/finviz

and used Jupyter Lab to execute the first example. Namely,

```
from finviz.screener import Screener

filters = ['exch_nasd', 'idx_sp500']  # Shows companies in NASDAQ which are in the S&P500
stock_list = Screener(filters=filters)  # Get the performance table and sort it by price ascending

print(stock_list)
```

I see the first line missing (the results print from the second row). However, this doesn't happen on a Mac OSX terminal. I am not sure what could be the issue. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem as well, here the solution I came up with, I thought I'd share

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from finviz.screener import Screener

# Example link:
# https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=sh_relvol_o5&o=-volume
filters = ['sh_relvol_o5'] 
stock_list_1 = Screener(filters=filters, table='Performance', order='-volume').to_csv(filename="stocks_1.csv")
stock_list_2 = Screener(filters=filters, table='Performance', order='volume').to_csv(filename="stocks_2.csv")
df = pd.read_csv("stocks_1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("stocks_2.csv")
item = df2.iloc[[-1]].copy()
item['No.'] = 1
new = pd.concat([item, df])
new = new.set_index('No.')
# optional cleanup
os.remove("stocks_1.csv")
os.remove("stocks_2.csv")
new # final dataframe
```